# Default Xib get loaded instead of desired Xib?

Tags: ios, localization, xib

In my Application I enabled the Localization for spanish Language . Sources like strings, Plist, Images etc are working fine without any problem except the xib files.

Instead of the xib of selected Language(spanish in my example) the View controller load default xib file

below is my bundle

[image]

And the screen shots of english and spanish Xibs respectively

EditViewController.xib(English)

[image]

EditViewController.xib(Spanish)

[image]

As seen in the above images I have translated the texts(in xib) into spanish for spanish xib
But the viewcontroller is loading same xib(default one) for both language. Help me to Show the desired xib.

**Note:-**
      The Save Button on the top left corner change it's text to the selected language(I set the identifier type of that UIBarButtonItem to "save")

Answer (score 0):

I think u have to change the language of your ipad or ur iPhone.

Your app should dettect that language and display the desired xib, on "EN" or "ES" folders.

The default folder that ios will use, is "EN" (English), so u can try to swap all files on "EN" to "ES" language.

Other opcion, is to use same xib for both languages, and use NSLocalizedString instead making 2 xibs.

Comment: Yes for sure I have changed the ipad language to spanish(as you said) before running the application

Comment: still I can't see the changes in the simulator